# Can you perform a ternary expression in a javascript string interpolation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, interpolation

I have this variable :

```
var foobar = "Hi, my name is #{name}";
```

But if name is not defined at load of the page.. I'd like it to save "unknown" instead.

But writing something like this :

```
var foobar = "Hi, my name is #{typeof name === 'undefined' ? 'unknown' : name}";
```

Still returns the error, `unknown variable name`

Comment: which is the templatting language used

Comment: What kind of syntax is `"Hi, my name is #{name}"`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat I think it's a Ruby thing. That's the only place I've seen that specific syntax.

Comment: @Mathletics: Too bad this is a JavaScript question ^_^

Comment: @Trip, Please specify the template language being used. There will be no good answers to your question otherwise.

Comment: @RocketHazmat indeed! All the more confusing for us, eh? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of making logic decisions within a string construct, do it outside for better performance and (far) more readable code:

`name = name||'unknown';`

Answer (score 3):

I think a better method would be:

```
var name = name || "Unknown";
var foobar = 'Hi my name is ' + name;
```

Comment: @f00bar sure, for a one-liner. But this misses the point if you have to do any serious client-side templating.

Comment: Agreed with @Mathletics. I also like this way of short-circuiting the need for a ternary operation by combining the type-independence of javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Just put name in there. If it is undefined or null, it will be "false".

```
var foobar = "Hi, my name is " + name ? name : 'unknown';
```

Comment: What syntax are you using here?

Comment: No idea. I was following the syntax that the OP was using. If his code is able to attempt to read what is inside the #{} (returning that name is undefined), then his issue should just be a matter of getting the ternary inside to work correctly, which is the point of the question.

Comment: What if his template doesn't support that syntax and is trying to read the expression as a variable name? ^_^

Comment: Then the point of the question is moot, and a different solution would be required. But I took the literal interpretation of the question, as seems to be the rule around here.

Comment: I thought maybe you knew the engine he was using :-P

Comment: Looks like Ruby. http://web.njit.edu/all_topics/Prog_Lang_Docs/html/ruby/syntax.html#string

Comment: Then why is it tagged `JavaScript`?

Comment: That would be a question for the OP.

Comment: Better? I just added the Ruby tag.

Comment: But is he *really* using Ruby, or is he using a JavaScript template engine that resembles Ruby?  The plot thickens :-)

Comment: A little. It didn't seem like an important question for the OP to answer. One of the replies has been accepted, so now there's not much of a point anymore.

Comment: There, I even removed that odd syntax from my answer as well.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to argue with you, I just wasn't sure what was going on in the OP's question :-P

Comment: That was what it seemed like in the beginning, but no worries.

Answer (score 0):

With javascript ES6 syntax you can write this expression as follows,

```js
const logName = (name) => `Hi, my name is ${name ? name : 'unknown'}`


console.log("foobar when name is undefined: ", logName());
console.log("foobar when name is abc: ", logName("abc"));
```

Comment: Pictures of text are a really unhelpful way to present text

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Updated the answer with code snippet. Thanks